# TFS 2010 Changes to sub-directories

Tags: tfs

I have a project under TFS. I decided to refactor the project by moving projects into subdirectories (physical sub-directories) and when I tried to check in or merge the changes, TFS didn't detect the changes in the subdirectory mappings as moves and renames. It detected the changes as deletes and adds.

Is there any way to make TFS understand that the subdirectories just changed for these projects.

Answer (score 1):

This is a confounding issue that unfortunately is not well understood.  I would use the "Move" command in Visual Studio Source Control Explorer to do all moves.  DO NOT do them in Windows explorer and expect TFS to pick up on them, it will not.

For a more detailed explanation of this problem, look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mitrik/archive/2009/05/28/changing-to-slot-mode-in-tfs-2010-version-control.aspx).  But basically the TFS team decided to use a new way to represent source control objects in the database for 2010 and all moves are actually renames now because of it.  They call it "slot mode".